# Can the opacity always remain constant when drawing something with paintbrush

Tags: gimp, transparency

When using the paintbrush tool in Gimp, the brightness decreases according to the pressure and movement of the mouse.

[image: irregular line]

For example, when I continue the line I drew in the picture above, it becomes irregular compared to before.

[image]

This is the what I want it to be

So what I want is that the opacity of the brush doesn't depend on mouse movement or hovering over the old line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can apply "pressure" with a mouse.

One thing that puts some variation on how the paintbrush works is "Brush dynamics":

[image]

Make sure it is set to "Dynamics off".

Otherwise, the paint brush interpolates pixels, so slight shakes may some edge pixels darker or lighter. If you want to draw a clean straight line:

- click on the start point
- depress the Shift key
- move the mouse to the end point: Gimp will draw a tracker line
- click again when on the end point: Gimp draws the line.

You can even ask Gimp to make sure that the line is exactly vertical, horizontal or set to 15-30-45-60-75 degrees (a.k.a. constrained angles)by also holding Ctrl while you move to the end point.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that the line left by the mouse is different depending on the position its position. Despite I click just once while using brushtool, the number and brightness of the dots left by the mouse changes depending on where the mouse is located. I want to remain this constant.

Comment: Hard to compare a straigh line and a wobbly line. When you are dealing with pixel-sized object anti-aliasing can have side effects. Maybe you want to use the Pencil instead of the Brush. It is not anti-aliased so you should et a constant color.